# How to use min-precision in d3d9

Tags: graphics, directx-9

I want to know how to use min-precision in d3d9. DX11 spec describes that min-precision enumeration is added into d3d9. However, When I write a pixel shader with min16float keyword and translate it with fxc.exe, it fails and reports "ps_3_0 doesnot support min-precision". So how can I use min-precision in d3d9?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** For pixel shader 3.0, use `half` instead of `min16float`.

The DirectX 11 minimum shader precision feature is supported for Direct3D Hardware Feature Level 9.x devices. On Feature level 9.x, the VS and PS can have different precisions which is what is expressed in the `AllOtherShaderStagesMinPrecision.AllOtherShaderStagesMinPrecision` field.

Direct3D 9 shader model 2.0 only required 24 bits of precision for pixel shaders, and supported 16 bits when using `half` or `_pp` types. The DirectX 11 shader precision feature support for the 9.x feature level profiles make use of this.

See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/shader-model-3#specifying-full-or-partial-precision).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Half type in hlsl is transformed into _pp modifier in dxbc sm3.